# Does Facebook Account Kit stops working if Facebook is blocked?

Tags: account-kit

I have noticed Account Kit is not working(it seems like it can't connect to the server) if Facebook is blocked and it only works if facebook is unblocked or if I use a VPN.

Comment: Well my _guess_ would be, yes, it’ll probably not work if Facebook is blocked. But for anything more definitive, your question is too vague, you’d need to properly explain what “not working” and “blocked” actually mean.

Comment: @misorude it seems like it can't connect to the server